# Treeview doesn't work well in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, treeview

My purpose:

I want to show treeview data in table. I use Angularjs and treeview to realize this feature. However, when the JS script get the data and give the data to treeview, the data will show for just a second and disappear.

html code like this:

```
<tbody id="understanding-content-table-body">
    <tr ng-repeat="(i, log) in understandingLogs">
        <td ng-repeat="item in log track by $index">{{item}}</td>
        <td>
            <div id="tree-{{i}}"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

And my JS code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i) {
    var id = '#tree-' + i;
    $(id).treeview({ data: tmp[i], levels: 0, showBorder: false, icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-minus" });
}
```

tmp is the data that want to show.

After debugging, I found that when the the JS script finished, another angularjs code will be executed, and then the treeview in the table will disappear. I think
that the treeview doesn't find the "tree-0", "tree-1"... because the html don't ready. And I execute the  command

```
$('#tree-0').treeview({ data: [{text:123}], levels: 0, showBorder: false, icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-minus" });
```

then the data will be shown in the table.

So my question is that, could I execute the JS script after the html is finished?

By the way, I have tried the

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {});
```

and

```
$('document').ready(function (){});
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: try using `ng-attr-id="tree-{{i}}"`, otherwise you might need to run a digest cycle (`$scope.$apply()`), or wrap it in `$timeout`

Comment: There is an `ng-treeview` available that you could possibly use instead of jQuery directly

Comment: Mixing jQuery and AngularJS like this is asking for problems. With the AngularJS framework, DOM manipulation should be done inside directives that are attached to the element of interest. That way the code is guaranteed to execute when AngularJS instantiates the element.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).